# Google RE2 doesn't recognize Unicode escape in regex

Tags: c++, regex, unicode, re2

I am developing an application, in C++, that validates configuration files with regex by using the Google RE2 library. The contents of the configuration files are read into an std::string;

So far, I declared this string that contains the regex expression:

```
const string EXPR_FAILED_FILE(R"([^\u0020-\u007E\n]|(\b.*(Mensagem|Antes|Loop|Movimentar|\|).*)|\\[0-9]{3,4})");
```

However, in this implementation below I am having some issues to detect some invalid characters in my test string (strInput)

```
bool checkStringConsistency(const string& strInput){
    RE2 re(EXPR_FAILED_FILE);
    bool b_matches = RE2::FullMatch(strInput, re);
    return b_matches;
}
```

When I run the code, I am getting these messages in the stderr:

```
re2/re2.cc:205: Error parsing '[^\u0020-\u007E\n]|(\b.*(Mensagem|Antes|Loop|Movimentar|\|).*)|\\[0-9]{3,4}': invalid escape sequence: \u
re2/re2.cc:890: Invalid RE2: invalid escape sequence: \u
```

It seems that the RE2 are not recognizing the `\u` sequence to seek a Unicode range of characters. I tested this expression at [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) and the invalid characters was detected normally there.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each regex engine has [its own syntax](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) and in RE2 you need to use `[^\x{0020}-\x{007E}\n]` instead of `[^\u0020-\u007E\n]`. See the [syntax document](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/ca93436e5b1be02f9f4bfca79b8202c400161994/doc/syntax.txt#L102):

```
Escape sequences:
\a  bell (== \007)
\f  form feed (== \014)
\t  horizontal tab (== \011)
\n  newline (== \012)
\r  carriage return (== \015)
\v  vertical tab character (== \013)
\*  literal «*», for any punctuation character «*»
\123    octal character code (up to three digits)
\x7F    hex character code (exactly two digits)
\x{10FFFF}  hex character code
\C  match a single byte even in UTF-8 mode
\Q...\E literal text «...» even if «...» has punctuation
```

`\u` is used to match an uppercase character and is marked as *NOT SUPPORTED*

Comment: OK. This suggested solution worked 100%. Thank you for the assistance.